# SQL Server intellisense does not refresh stored procedure and function list

Tags: sql, sql-server, intellisense, ssms

I am trying to learn Microsoft SQL server 2014. I have defined some functions and stored procedures, but SQL server intellisence does not show latest ones and underlines them as an error.

[image]

Although SQL server shows as an error when I execute it works fine. My question is why SQL server underlines the statement, even though it works.

[image]

Comment: If it works like SQL Server 2008 SSMS does, it's a limitation of the way Intellisense works for SQL Server - you have to refresh the Intellisense cache for the query window to recognize the new objects. Try Ctrl-Shift-R (http://www.sureshjoshi.com/development/ssms-refreshing-intellisense/)

Comment: Just use `Edit > Intellisense > Refresh Local Cache` and it works again as expected

Comment: Look for [CTRL+SHIFT+R](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx) **Refresh Local Cache**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will happen any time you create a new table, procedure, function, etc or modify a database object (add/remove columns on a table for example).

You just need to refresh the Intellisense cache to have it look for new objects.  `ctrl+shift+r` should do the trick, or use the menu option `Edit > Intellisense > Refresh Local Cache` as one of the comments suggested

[image]

Comment: Just to elaborate on *why* this is necessary, consider the alternative; SSMS would have to poll each database to see if there are any new objects and update the UI if there are. That's a lot of load to put on the server if there are a lot of clients connected.

Answer (score 3):

To refresh the intellisense so it incorporates your latest stored procedures or table changes:

1. Open any stored procedure (right-click and choose Modify)
2. From the Menu, choose Edit > Intellisense > **Refresh Local Cache**

That should do it!